# How lock/unlock mouse scroll on PHP/html/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-events

In my project I have a dialog window that arrears when user clicks on link

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="flashnotice()" >Dialog window</a>
```

Then window appears it runs Javascript function `flashnotice()` and in this function I need to blocked mouse scroll, and when user close this window (user clicks on image) mouse scroll release, I prefer listening this image on jQuery and when be a click run new Javascript function that release mouse scroll.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `style="overflow:hidden"`  on `body` tag when box appears. It will lock mouse scroll or use `position:fixed` on a box.

The best way to "freeze" a page is to make transparent or half transparent box (100% width, 100% height) between a page and your box and set `position:fixed`to your box. This is the way Lightbox/Fancybox works.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot lock scrolling, you can use CSS fixed/absolute [positioning feature](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) to fix position of your element.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is possible using a script like :

```
function kill(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
$(document).bind('scroll', kill); // Lock Wheel
$(document).unbind('scroll'); // Unlock Wheel
```